# how to implement flutter web push notification

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I'm wondering if I can implement push notification in flutter web?
I saw that I can create push notification for mobile app with `firbase_messaging` but is it possible to use it for web app? or any other alternative to accomplish it?

Comment: As of now, the Flutter team haven't yet made `firebase_messaging` plugin available on the web platform. The plugin only works on Android & iOS. Moreover you can use the firebase messaging outside of Flutter app with only html&js, but I think you don't want this way. Hope they support web too with `firebase_messaging`

Comment: @Mohith7548 I just want it to happen I don't care how? could you please tell me how can I do that with js and html? cuz I've never developed web with those

Comment: This is a good documentation about it https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client

Comment: I tried but was stuck with the error `An error occurred while retrieving token: FirebaseError: Messaging: A problem occured while subscribing the user to FCM: Request contains an invalid argument. (messaging/token-subscribe-failed). (messaging/token-subscribe-failed)`

Answer (score 10):

I'm considering that you've already set up a flutter-web project and have a firebase project.

In the flutter project folder, open index.html and place these scripts in the head section.

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.4/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.4/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.4/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
```

Then, in the body, append the code before main.dart.js script is loaded.

```
  <script src="./firebase-messaging-sw.js"></script>
  <script src="myjs.js"></script>
  <script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
```

(where myjs.js is any file where you want to write code, but firebase-messaging-sw.js must be there.)

Now, create two files in the index.html directory:

1. firebase-messaging-sw.js
2. myjs.js (whatever name you chose)

In firebase-messaging-sw.js, just write

```
console.log("")
```

In myjs.js (again, whatever file name you chose), write following code:

```
var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "YOUR_API_KEY",
    authDomain: "~~~~~~",
    databaseURL: "~~~~~",
    projectId: "~~~~~~",
    storageBucket: "~~~~~~",
    messagingSenderId: "~~~~~~",
    appId: "~~~~~~~~~~~~~",
    measurementId: "~~~~~~~~~~~"
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
firebase.analytics();

var messaging = firebase.messaging()

messaging.usePublicVapidKey('Your Key');

messaging.getToken().then((currentToken) => {
    console.log(currentToken)
})
```

You can find these credentials from the firebase console's project settings. You will find the firebaseConfig details in the web app you'd have added.
For the key, you'll have to generate a new pair. Go to the Cloud Messaging in the project settings, and there you can generate a new pair.

When you'll run your app (flutter run -d chrome), you can find your token in the console log. Copy that token.

From the Cloud Messaging Section from the side drawer, we can compose a new notification.
Enter whatever you like in title and text. 
Click on send test message.
Paste the token you copied from console and click on Test.

[image: Screenshot of the notification]

You can see the notification popped up.

You can refer [this article](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client)
and [firebase documentation](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-add-push-notifications-to-a-web-app-with-firebase-528a702e13e1/)
for more info.

Comment: Its okay for just receiving the notification. How can I get notification title and content and How to use it in UI?

Comment: I followed the instructions above. My site now asks for permissions to send notifications but when I send them through the Cloud Messaging web console nothing happens. I tested this on both local and external hosted environments. 
Do I need to edit anything in the pubspec.yaml? Any other recommendations?

Comment: Another thing to consider is that messaging will not work for the Safari browser. Your web app will display a blank page. This is because FCM is not supported by Safari https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/environments_js-sdk

Answer (score 4):

```
To implement push notifications and open the app on notification click you need to Change in three files.


1) Firebase-Messaging-sw.js


importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.23.0/firebase-app.js");
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.23.0/firebase-messaging.js");
firebase.initializeApp({
         apiKey: "",
           authDomain: "",
           projectId: "",
           storageBucket: "",
           messagingSenderId: "",
           appId: "",
           measurementId: ""
});
const messaging = firebase.messaging();


messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function (payload) {
    const promiseChain = clients
        .matchAll({
            type: "window",
            includeUncontrolled: true
        })
        .then(windowClients => {
            for (let i = 0; i < windowClients.length; i++) {
                const windowClient = windowClients[i];
                windowClient.postMessage(payload);
            }
        })
        .then(() => {
            const title = payload.notification.title;
            const options = {
                body: payload.notification.score
              };
            return registration.showNotification(title, options);
        });
    return promiseChain;
});
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function (event) {
    console.log('notification received: ', event)
});


index.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!--
      If you are serving your web app in a path other than the root, change the
      href value below to reflect the base path you are serving from.

      The path provided below has to start and end with a slash "/" in order for
      it to work correctly.

      Fore more details:
      * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base
    -->
    <base href="/">

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
    <meta name="description" content="Share pictures and information with other collectors of historical artifacts">

    <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="Militrade">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">

    <!-- Favicon -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico"/>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico"/>

    <title>Militrade</title>
    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
</head>
<body>
<script>
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    window.addEventListener('load', function () {
     navigator.serviceWorker.register("/firebase-messaging-sw.js");
   });
  }
 </script>
<!-- This script installs service_worker.js to provide PWA functionality to
     application. For more information, see:
     https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers -->
<!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->

<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-app.js"></script>

<!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
   https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->

<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>

<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>

<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>

<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-messaging.js"></script>

<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.20.0/firebase-storage.js"></script>

<script>
  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
  var firebaseConfig = {
     apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: "",
    measurementId: ""
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  firebase.analytics();
</script>
<script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    let useHtml = true;
    if(useHtml) {
      window.flutterWebRenderer = "html";
    } else {
      window.flutterWebRenderer = "canvaskit";
    }
  </script>



<script>
    if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
      window.addEventListener("load", function () {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register("/flutter_service_worker.js");
        navigator.serviceWorker.register("/firebase-messaging-sw.js");
      });
    }
  </script>


</body>
</html>

then create push_notification_services.dart file for send push notification


import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

final String serverToken =
    '';

Future<Map<String, dynamic>> sendPushNotification(
    {@required String message,
    @required String fcmToken,
    @required String title}) async {
  print(fcmToken);

  await http.post(
    Uri.parse('https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send'),
    headers: <String, String>{
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'key=$serverToken',
    },
    body: jsonEncode(
      <String, dynamic>{
        'notification': <String, dynamic>{
           "click_action" : ".EditPostPage",
          'body': message,
          'title': '$title',
          'sound': 'default'
        },
        'priority': 'high',
        'data': <String, dynamic>{
          'click_action': 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',
          'id': '1',
          'status': 'done'
        },
        'to': fcmToken.toString().trim(),
      },
    ),
  );
  final Completer<Map<String, dynamic>> completer =
      Completer<Map<String, dynamic>>();

 
  return completer.future;
}


After 3 days I can do it and it's properly working well for me. hope it's helpful for you.
```

Comment: I am unable to open app on notification click, can you help me?

Comment: say what's the issue

Comment: I receive the notification for web app but when I click nothing happens. I want it to open the web app.

Comment: Why are you registering `/firebase-messaging-sw.js` twice in index.html?

Comment: I added whole code, but web stuck at launching after requesting notification permission